# object kafka is not a member of package org.apache

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka

When importing the java drivers into my scala project, Im hit with the following message on compilation: `object kafka is not a member of package org.apache`. Here are how my import statements are setup:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.{Callback, KafkaProducer, ProducerRecord, RecordMetadata}
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer
```

I've tried running `activator clean` and `activator clean-file`a few times already with any success.

EDIT: This might help
[image]

Comment: is related JARs in your classpath?

Comment: @AdrianShum When I start to type in Kafka related things, intelli j auto-import adds those import paths which is making me assume that it is. The proper statements are within my SBT build for what its worth.

Comment: You got this in BUILD classpath does not mean the JARs exists in your RUNTIME classpath.  It highly depends on how you package the result and how you run it.  If you are running from IntelliJ then it will be good that you explicitly mention it  :)  btw, you said `I've tried running ... with any success.` do you mean you can successfully run it  (with success) or cannot (without any success) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out, a major gotcha of SBT and Activator for that matter is that it doesn't update automatically if new files are added. As such the solution for me was to call `reload` in the activator console I have running for continuously running tests as I develop.